# Return filtered array with only elements that match given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, filter

I want a method that goes through a posts array, and returns a new array with only the elements that match a certain value of the `userId` property.

For example:

```
let postsArr = [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "userId": 3,
        "id": 5
      }
    ]
```

Say I want to return only the items with `userId: 2`.

(Something like...)

```
let filteredArr = postsArr.method( post => post.userId === 2)
```

Which would (ideally) return:

```
[
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 4
      }
    ]
```

I'm sure it would be something like .map() or .filter(), but I can quite get my head round how to do it, or what the best method is in this case.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you not look at the MDN docs for filter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: This is one reason I do not like `arrow` functions for `array` functions. Still, start by logging `post`. See what it gives you and then try to get what you want

Comment: @Rajesh What reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: People do not understand that they can do `=>{}` and debug their code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pretty much there to be honest..

```js
let postsArr = [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "userId": 3,
        "id": 5
      }
    ];

var farray = postsArr.filter((a) => a.userId === 2);

console.log(farray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES5. We used to do this.

```
var newarray = postsArr.filter(function(obj){
     return obj.userId === 2
})
```

Comment: I was close... I just wasn't sure how to deal with the contents of the function. So it just returns the element if it matches the condition. Got it :)